# PHP compare broken on Eclipse 4.7

Tags: eclipse, comparison, pdt

I need feedback on Eclipse PDT (Eclipse 4.7).

I'm facing a compare bug as describe in :

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=507821

My question is :

Can you give me some feedback ? Maybe you can help me figure if it's a real bug or just a problem on my computer.

thx guys

Comment: Note that Eclipse 4.7 (Oxygen) is still only in Milestone builds and will not be fully released until next June (2017). You might be better using the current 4.6 (Neon) release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the bug report it looks like the PHP code is trying to use a method in an internal Eclipse class which has been removed in Eclipse 4.7 (which is still underdevelopment). Because of this the PHP code is not current compatible with Eclipse 4.7

This method appears to be present in the current release Eclipse Neon (4.6) so you should trying running with Eclipse 4.6.

Comment: Yeah I have a full 4.6 working IDE, for the 4.7 I m not sure my java version is correct (1.8)

Comment: Java 8 is OK for 4.7. This problem appears to be the PHP code is not obeying the rules and is using internal Eclipse classes which are not guaranteed to stay the same between releases. I have lost track of the number of times I have seen things fail because they didn't follow the rules.